# Windows Command to make the next boot, show as in first time booting the system - and ask to create username

Tags: windows, command-line

Could anyone kindly remind me what was the Windows Command to make the Windows' actual installation, to ask to create Username and Password as if it was the First Time you'r booting the system?

I remember I've used this command once, but I can't remember what command was it. I had made a clean installation of Windows, installed all drivers and softwares that the client would use, and then, I used this command to get the system to ask to create an username and password, the next time the system would boot. I just can't remember the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The command was Sysprep.

Comment: Here's a turorial https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2014/05/how-to-sysprep-sysprep-is-a-great-and-powerful-tool-and-easy-too-if-you-know-how-step-by-step/

Comment: please accept your own answer. That will help others who read the question in future